# General formula of coordinates of a point on an arc given the centre of the arc, radius and the starting and ending angle of arc wrt horizontal.

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

I am given the centre of an arc, the starting and ending angles of the arc wrt the horizontal and the radius of the arc.
I want a general formula that I can use to get the coordinates of points on the arc in terms of the radius, coordinates of the centre and the angles.

How do I calculate that?

[Clarifying Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5MHb.jpg)

Edit: The angle(s) do not necessarily have to be the starting or the ending angles. It is completely okay if the formula is a function of the angle of the line connecting the centre to that point on the arc instead. (Please refer to the Image in the link above for clarification)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Do you know how to get an equation for a circle?

Comment: Yes, are you talking about this; (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 = r^2 where (a,b,c) is the centre and r is the radius?